How to dim push button led switch?
I bought an audio amplifier which has this LED push-button to power it on & off:
The LED is too bright, it's a bit annoying, so I wanted to dim it, but I have no clue how to do that. Would it be possible to solder a resistor somewhere to dim it?
Here are the wiring instructions:

And here is an electrical schematic:

LED voltage 9-24 V, 220 V
LED rated current   <24 V: <20 mA;     >24 V: <10 mA
Can someone explain to me how this works and where I could solder a resistor to dim the LED? Thanks a lot!
Edit: I forgot to mention that I did try to solder a 1k resistor between 1 & NO, but this resulted in an always on LED without dim change

Is it not simpler to cover it with a bit of a transparent tape, or paint on it with a marker pen?

Assuming you've got the LED voltage 9 - 24 V version, you disconnect either terminal 1 or 2 and connect the resistor instead and reconnect the wire to the other end of the resistor. This puts the resistor in series with the LED only.
Since the LED is designed to work over a wide range, 9 - 24 V, there may be a transistorised current limiting device inside. This will tend to keep the brightness constant until the terminals 1 - 2 voltage gets below 9 V. At 1 kΩ you should be able to see a difference. If it's too dim then try 500 Ω (2 × 1k in parallel).

Thank you, that worked perfectly. I ended up with a 200k resistor.

200k sounds very unlikely to work. It would give you a current of $ \frac {24}{220k} =  0.1 mA. That would be very, very dim.

It is very dim ;-). In fact during the day I'm not able to see that it is ON. But in the night the light is visible and it is exactly what I wanted :-).

All you have to do is connect a resistor to one side (or the other) of the LED connection(s).  Either like this:

Or like this:

Start with 1Meg, then 100K, then 10K, then 1K, then 100, then 10, etc. until it lights up at the brightness that you want. I suggested this because I don't really know what voltage you have, or if there is constant-current (or other) regulation inside the "black box" of the component. Keep dividing the number in half until you get just the brightness you want. Look up binary search for other examples.

Thanks for the reply. I installed a 200k resistor.
